# Adding a back button in a LightSwitch details page

Tags: lightswitch-2013

I have created my screens using the 'common screen set' template option.

From the details page I have a button to edit the details.
I need to add a back button (which redirect to browse page/previous page) near to the edit button.

How can I do this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your going back to a browse screen, you would simply create a new button, and add this code to "Edit Execute Code"

```
myapp.BrowseScreen.Back_execute = function (screen) {
    myapp.showBrowseOrders();
};
```

alternatively if you add a button, and you select the browse screen from the Tab list, this will also re-direct you to a browse screen.

in terms of going to the previous page, I would use `myapp.commitChanges();` this would save the changes on the screen from a custom save button created by you (validation can be added on here), or alternatively you can use `myapp.cancelChanges();` which also navigates back but no changes will be saved. Both of these commands above would take you back to the previous page.

Comment: a note to this though, if browsing back from a dialog screen to a full screen, then myapp.showBrowseOrders(); may not work properly, and open the browse window in a dialog window, im looking at this now myself